# Объединение двух списков в один без использования if, циклов

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x, список, функциональное-программирование

Есть два списка. Например:

`list_a = [1, 2]`
`list_b = [3, 4]`

Нужно создать список `list_c`, поочередно добавляя элемент то с первого списка, то с другого. Получится вот так: `[1, 3, 2, 4]`.

Нужно написать **без использования if, циклов**... Только с помощью функционального программирования. Может как-то с помощью рекурсии?

Comment: связанный вопрос [Interleaving two lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7946798/4279) в частности: [`more_itertools.interleave()`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/more_itertools/more.html#interleave)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
In [143]: from itertools import chain

In [144]: list(chain.from_iterable(zip(list_a, list_b)))
Out[144]: [1, 3, 2, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> [x for z in zip(list_a, list_b) for x in z]
[1, 3, 2, 4]
```

Comment: Нельзя по условию использовать циклы

Comment: Здесь нет циклов, и пусть слово `for` не вводит вас в заблуждение. Это чисто функциональное решение.